# JPA/Hibernate query with class name?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

In this example `com.test.Cat` extends `com.test.Animal` and there is no field `DB` in `CAT` table of `com.test.Cat` explicitly defining its type (it wasn't me).

When I query my animals from DB I get a collection of Animals.

It is possible to sort them by class name:

```
order by r.class
```

but is there a way to use class name as a criteria? For example I would like to get all animals expect dogs. But no luck - even this does not work:

```
where r.class = ?      (String "ccc.test.Cat")
```

as I get an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at org.hibernate.type.IntegerType.set(IntegerType.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.param.PositionalParameterSpecification.bind(PositionalParameterSpecification.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:514)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1589)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:696)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:361)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1148)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:67)
```

Comment: Could you post the class and table definitions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [chapter 14.9](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html_single/#queryhql-where) of the documentation, you shouldn't use double quotes:

> The special property class accesses
>   the discriminator value of an instance
>   in the case of polymorphic
>   persistence. A Java class name
>   embedded in the where clause will be
>   translated to its discriminator value.
>
> ```
> from Cat cat where cat.class = DomesticCat
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the example. The original code used '?' for prepared statement.

Comment: @Petteri I just tested this HQL query and it works as expected (without quotes or double quotes). It's not a `String` that is expected, not sure you can use a prepared statement here (at least not with `setString`)